# Windows Azure - Mobile Services - SQL Databases

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I'm new to Windows Azure. I have briefly played around with settings up a Mobile Service and downloading the gendered Android sample App. Viewing the MSDN Channel 9 tutorials and viewing the Azure documention.

If I set up a database schema using Windows Azure SQL Databases how do I plug this back into my Azure Mobile Service (for example: so I have referential integrity in my database model, restricted column sizes, etc). I know once the Mobile Service and the Database are the same name then Azure Mobile Service picks it up.

I want to have the SQL Database ready for when the mobile device posts data to the Mobile Service. What I have noticed is that when I specify the SQL Database table and tried to insert data into it, it is failing. Is there a difference between data format passed from mobile device and the SQL tables ? Where can I find information about setting this up correctly?

SQL Table example, so I want to have constraints on the size of the data for example, firstname below so that it will only hold an entry of max 15 chars.

```
CREATE TABLE Users (

id                          BigInt IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
firstname                   VarChar(15),
lastname                    VarChar(15) ,
email                       VarChar(255),
age                         Int
);
```

So when I do an insert it does not fail (as it is doing at present). Where is the documentation around Azure Mobile Services and SQL Databases setup etc ?

Or do I do all this via the Azure Mobile Services Tables & Columns via Mobile Services Tab --> Mobile Service Entry --> Data Tab --> Table Name -- Columns Tab --> Add Column

The Add Column only supports 4 data types: String, Number, Date, Boolean and the Column name.

Have I got this all wrong about using Mobile Services and SQL Tables ? Do I need to use Azure SQL Databases at all and just use the Mobile Services Tables/Columns ? If so how can I configure the Azure Table columns to hold precise data sizes as in limit the firstname above to 15 characters above, the Azure columns just seem to be generic size String and Numbers. The only way I have seen this limited is in the Mobile Services Insert/Update/Delete/Read functions where the data is checked e.g.

if (firstname > 15) then
// do something: alert the user firstname is too long

If this is the case how do I create the Mobile Service Tables/Columns entries via a generation script ?

Have I missed something fundamental as regards Windows Mobile Services, that is, it's Tables/Columns are completely separate from Azure SQL Databases ?